# Objective C NSTimer not firing until program ends

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer, scheduling

In AppDelegate I have an NSMutableArray with a set of classes that are processed in a background method (songs being played).  That part of the Application is working fine.  I setup the delegate method and receive status on the work at the conclusion of each item of the array.  I wanted to add an NSSlider to display the status of each array item being processed.  I tested the slider on a single entity from within the AppDelegate and got the results I expected.  The problem is when I’m processing the queue the NSTimer is not firing until the unit of work is completed as if delayed.  I suspect I’m not scheduling it properly (because the timer worked on a single song with the same code from within AppDelegate).

#### AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource,
    NSTableViewDelegate, NSSharingServiceDelegate,
    NSSharingServicePickerDelegate, SongPlayerDelegate>

-(void) songPlayer:(SongPlayer *)player didSomething:(DesktopEntity *)entity;
-(void) songPlayer:(SongPlayer *)player updateSlider:(double)result;
```

#### ApplDelegate.m

```
-(void)previewQueue:(DesktopEntity *)entity {
    …
// schedule work
    _queuePlayer = [[SongPlayer alloc] init];
    _queuePlayer.delegate = self;
    [_queuePlayer performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playMyQueue:) withObject:_queue];
}
```

#### SongPlayer.h

```
@protocol SongPlayerDelegate;
@interface SongPlayer : NSObject {
id<SongPlayerDelegate> __unsafe_unretained delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SongPlayerDelegate> delegate;
-(id)playMyQueue:NSMutableArray;
@end

@protocol SongPlayerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)songPlayer:(SongPlayer *)player didSomething:(id)enity;
- (void)songPlayer:(SongPlayer *)player updateSlider:(double)result;
@end
-(id) playMyQueue:(id)entity {
…

    NSDictionary *dict = [(DesktopSoundEntity *)entity tagDictionary];
    NSString *dur = [dict objectForKey:kTagDuration];
    _songDurration = [dur doubleValue];
    _then = [NSDate date];
    if (_myTimer) {
        [_myTimer invalidate];
        _myTimer = nil;
    }
    _myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.75 target:self
            selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self playSong];
    [self passBackURL:entity];
    return nil;
}
- (void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    double now = ([_then timeIntervalSinceNow]*-1);
    NSLog(@"now-> %f", now);
    double sec = (now / _songDurration) *100;
    NSLog(@"now-> %f", sec);
    if (sec > 100) {
        [_myTimer invalidate];
        _myTimer = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"SLIDER SHOULD BE UPDATING");
    [self.delegate songPlayer:self updateSlider:sec];
}
```

The slider isn’t updated until the playMyQueue method completes, I see the bar jump and I get the NSLog message.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please 1) Post your real code (`Return nil;` does not compile) - 2) Take your time to format/indent the code to make it better readable.

Comment: Thanks Martin, should have been return nil; I'm a new at this, will try to fix

Comment: Do you have a [slider display|; after changing the slider's value?

Comment: What does `-playSong` do? It certainly appears as if you're blocking the main thread (or running it in a different run loop mode) during playback.

Comment: DigiMonk, I'll give that a try, but I never get to the NSLog(@"SLIDER SHOULD BE UPDAIING") statement just before sending the value from the PlaySong method (see above).  However when the song finishes, the message and the slider start working.

Comment: Ben, it is a simple Audio Player that uses AVFoundation.  Strange thing is that I get notified at songs end, and then the slider code starts working.  I try moving in back into AppController under the delegated methods but same thing happens.  I agree I'm not scheduling it properly but I'm at a loss.

Comment: @BobFields OK . May be you can move some code into songPlayer so it handles < all > the playing stuff (including updating a slider...) itself.

Comment: DigiMonk, I think that may dirty up the class, seems that I should be able to pass the status (value) on, and let the AppDelegate control all of the window (I-O) attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timers won't fire unless they are scheduled in a thread with a running run loop.  `performSelectorInBackground:..` makes no such guarantee that the work will be scheduled in a thread with a runloop and, in any case, as soon as the invoked selector exits, the thread may be reaped.

To fix, move that timer to a thread with a running run loop.  The main thread is likely the best choice given that you are mucking w/UI bits.

Comment: bbum, thanks; you have given me the area to look at.  I'm new to Objective C, and not quite sure where I need to insert the loop so I can get a smooth glide on the slider.  I'm thinking the value is better derived in the SongPlayer Method and the value passed to the AppDelegate that takes care of the screen, so I got to figure out how to make that happen.  Again thanks for the lead.